# Is it possible to use the Mongo $natural operator in Spring Data?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I was looking to use the `$natural` operator in Spring Data MongoDB, as documented here:

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/meta/natural/

Is this possible to do using the `MongoTemplate` class?  Thanks.

Comment: The Spring Data MongoDB annotation `@org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query` allows you to pass a native MongoDB query to the MongoDB engine.  You could try `@Query("{ $natural : 1 }")` or `@Query("{ $natural : -1 }")` on a repository method to see if it works for you.

Comment: Because of the way the system is architected, I can't use the repository methods, only `MongoTemplate` (should have clarified that in my original post).

Comment: `MongoTemplate` has a few overloaded `doFind` methods.  Do take a look at `List<T> doFind(String collectionName, DBObject query, DBObject fields, Class<T> entityClass)`.  You can pass instances of `BasicDBObject` for the second and third parameters.  `new BasicDBObject().append("natural", 1")` should be sufficient for the second parameter.

Comment: I'll have to take a look at that, thanks.

Comment: Seems like that method is protected, unfortunately.

Comment: Use `List<T> find(Query, Class<T>, String)` which calls `doFind` internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use `$natural` in at least three styles where 1. and 2. are probably what you're looking for:

### 1. Using `Sort` with `Query`

```
Query query = new Query().with(new Sort(Direction.ASC, "$natural"));
```

use the query afterwards with `MongoTemplate`. The query carries a sort document like:

`{ "$natural" : 1}`

### 2. Using `BasicQuery`

`BasicQuery` allows using own `DBObject`s for the query document, the fields ("projection") and sorting.

```
BasicQuery basicQuery = new BasicQuery(new BasicDBObject());
basicQuery.setSortObject(new BasicDBObject("$natural", 1));
```

### 3. Using `execute` and `CollectionCallback`

This is the most extensive way in which you're getting access to the `DBCollection` and you can use the native MongoDB driver API. See [Spring Data Mongo docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.executioncallback) for more details.

Comment: RE: "1. Using Sort with Query". There is nothing on the Spring Data Sort class that accounts for `$natural`. So to clarify solution 1, "$natural" is being used as a property name to somewhat sneakily add the $natural operator to the query.